# Animated charts in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm doing my first tests with pyqtchart but becouse of the poor documentation about animated charts I've encountered some issuses. I built a chart that shows the 'sin', 'cos' and 'tan' functions (approximating the value of the tangent) and to make it live I've built a thread that clear and repaint the chart every time.
It works but I don't know if it's the correct way or the most efficent way to do it. I found an example hosted on [github](https://gist.github.com/Overdrivr/ed140520493e5d0f248d) but it's not realy clear for me.

I'dont understand if this's the 'offical way' to do it or if pyqtgraph provides some built-in functions to automate it.
I will be realy greatful for anyone who could give me some advice.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import pyqtgraph as pg
import math
import numpy as np
import sys
import time

class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 0.95)
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot.setAspectLocked(lock=True, ratio=0.01)
        self.plot.setYRange(-3, 3)
        self.widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.setLayout(self.widget_layout)

    def plot_data(self, data):
        self.plot.clear()
        self.plot.plot(range(0, 720), data[0], pen=pg.mkPen(color='g', width=2))
        self.plot.plot(range(0, 720), data[1], pen=pg.mkPen(color='r', width=2))
        self.plot.plot(range(0, 720), data[2], pen=pg.mkPen(color='y', width=2))

class Thread(QThread):
    sig_plot = pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sig_plot.connect(gui.plot_data)

    def run(self):
        sin_func = np.empty(720)
        cos_func = np.empty(720)
        tan_func = np.empty(720)
        cont = 0
        while True:
            indx = 0
            for ang in range(cont, cont + 720):
                rad = math.radians(ang)
                cos = math.cos(rad)
                sin = math.sin(rad)
                if cos != 0: tan = sin / cos
                else: tan = sin / 0.00000000001
                sin_func[indx] = sin
                cos_func[indx] = cos
                if tan >= -3 and tan <= 3: tan_func[indx] = tan
                else: tan_func[indx] = np.NaN
                indx += 1
            data = [sin_func, cos_func, tan_func]
            self.sig_plot.emit(data)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if cont == 720: cont = 0
            else: cont += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Gui()
    gui.show()
    thread = Thread()
    thread.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I should've been more specific, what I don't understand is if this is the 'official way' or if pyqtgraph provides some built-in functions to automate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official way to make animations in pyqtgraph, but the one you sample is not the best because the threads in a GUI are only necessary when there is a heavy task but the task of creating the arrays is not, another mistake is to clean and create the plots, in these cases it is better to reuse. And finally it is better to use the power of calculation of numpy at the level of matrices and arrays than to make a loop.

Considering the above I have implemented a class that calls the function generate_data every certain interval of time with the appropriate index and generates an infinite loop with the help of a QTimer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class TimeLine(QtCore.QObject):
    frameChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, interval=60, loopCount=1, parent=None):
        super(TimeLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self._startFrame = 0
        self._endFrame = 0
        self._loopCount = loopCount
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.on_timeout)
        self._counter = 0
        self._loop_counter = 0
        self.setInterval(interval)

    def on_timeout(self):
        if self._startFrame <= self._counter < self._endFrame:
            self.frameChanged.emit(self._counter)
            self._counter += 1
        else:
            self._counter = 0
            self._loop_counter += 1

        if self._loopCount > 0: 
            if self._loop_counter >= self.loopCount():
                self._timer.stop() 

    def setLoopCount(self, loopCount):
        self._loopCount = loopCount

    def loopCount(self):
        return self._loopCount

    interval = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, fget=loopCount, fset=setLoopCount)

    def setInterval(self, interval):
        self._timer.setInterval(interval)

    def interval(self):
        return self._timer.interval()

    interval = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, fget=interval, fset=setInterval)

    def setFrameRange(self, startFrame, endFrame):
        self._startFrame = startFrame
        self._endFrame = endFrame

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self._counter = 0
        self._loop_counter = 0
        self._timer.start()


class Gui(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 0.95)
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot.setAspectLocked(lock=True, ratio=0.01)
        self.plot.setYRange(-3, 3)
        widget_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        widget_layout.addWidget(self.plot)

        self._plots = [self.plot.plot([], [], pen=pg.mkPen(color=color, width=2)) for color in ("g", "r", "y")]
        self._timeline = TimeLine(loopCount=0, interval=10)
        self._timeline.setFrameRange(0, 720)
        self._timeline.frameChanged.connect(self.generate_data)
        self._timeline.start()

    def plot_data(self, data):
        for plt, val in zip(self._plots, data):
            plt.setData(range(len(val)), val)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def generate_data(self, i):
        ang = np.arange(i, i + 720)
        cos_func = np.cos(np.radians(ang)) 
        sin_func = np.sin(np.radians(ang))
        tan_func = sin_func/cos_func
        tan_func[(tan_func < -3) | (tan_func > 3)] = np.NaN
        self.plot_data([sin_func, cos_func, tan_func])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Gui()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, some parts of your implementation result complex for me but I've understood the mean, I always use the threads for every task becouse i thought was the only way but QTimer can fix it and I didn't know about the .setData(). Your code seems realy interesting and I'm gonna study it, tanks again.

Comment: @FabioCescon QThread should always be the last option, IMHO, since transmitting data from one thread to another takes some time. and setData replaces the clear and when creating new plots unnecessarily. On the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour] :-)